# How to have a large matrix of tf.zero shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

```
print("sequences",len(sequences))
print("seq_length",(seq_length))
print("vocab size",(vocab_size))
X = tf.zeros((len(sequences), seq_length, vocab_size), dtype=tf.bool)
y = tf.zeros((len(sequences), vocab_size), dtype=tf.bool)
```

**Output**

```
sequences 30373553
seq_length 30
vocab size 1290174

ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-1bd9b1544ba0> in <module>()
      2 print("seq_length",(seq_length))
      3 print("vocab size",(vocab_size))
----> 4 X = tf.zeros((len(sequences), seq_length, vocab_size), dtype=tf.bool)
      5 y = tf.zeros((len(sequences), vocab_size), dtype=tf.bool)
      6 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[30373553,30,1290174] and type bool on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu [Op:Fill] name: zeros/
```

Working on tensorflow 2.0
I want to make a matrix of zeroes of shape [30373553,30,1290174]
when runing the same code on TensorFlow 1.5 there was no such error but giving this error when working on Tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each `bool` element uses 1 byte of memory, your tensor of shape `[30373553, 30, 1290174]` will take about 1200 TB of memory to materialize. That's a lot of memory...

I'm guessing that this didn't error out in TensorFlow 1.5 because of the old deferred-execution paradigm, where you can call `tf.zeros([30373553, 30, 1290174])` without any issue because the symbolic tensor returned by the call won't be actually allocated in memory until you call `tf.Session.run()` on a tf.Graph that contains the tensor. In TensorFlow 2.0, however, eager execution will perform the memory allocation as soon as the call is made.

Comment: +1. From context in the original post, it looks like a sparse matrix might be appropriate; something like `tf.sparse.SparseTensor(tf.zeros((0, 3), tf.int64), [], (30373553, 30, 1290174))` will get you started.

Comment: Right. SparseTensor is one way to go. It's also possible that the OP is trying to ingest a large dataset for training, in which case `tf.data.Dataset` should be used. `tf.data.Dataset` can materialize the data in memory one batch at a time, so it can avoid memory issues like this.